# can I use the function CreateProcess inside process that compiled with x64 for calling process that compiled with x32?

Tags: 64-bit

Or I need to compile the x32 process into x64 process and then only to use CreateProcess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is no problem creating a process that is x86 using CreateProcess even know your application is running as x64.  Both processes have their own user space and own separate processes.